# app.config file in c# class library

Tags: c#-4.0

I m having a class library project which is referenced in my windows application project. One of the method of class library returns all the key value pair which is stored in my app.config file, when i m calling this method in my windows project there comes a error as "sequence contains no element". How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Paste the code that is causing the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an application is run, a new
application domain is created
Several different instantiations of an application can exist on the same
machine at the same time, and each has its own application domain

Types loaded into one application domain are distinct from the same type loaded into
another application domain, and instances of objects are not directly shared between application domains.

Use of a class library does not
cause the creation of a new application domain. Instead, a class library is loaded into the application domain
that uses it. For instance, when an application uses a class library, that class library is loaded into the
application domain for that application. If an application uses a class library A that itself uses a class
library B, then both A and B are loaded into the application domain for the application